# Simple read/write lock implementation without starvation

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, mutex

I've built a read/write lock and have been testing it without encountering any problems. It was made to avoid writer starvation, but I believe it works against reader starvation as well. I've seen alternatives online, but was wondering if this is a solid implementation.

If you use a normal shared mutex, new read actions can still be queued, which will prevent write actions from ever being processed while there is any read action present. This will cause starvation. I used a second mutex which will be locked by the write process and prevents any new read processes to be queued. Thank you!

```
class unique_priority_mutex
{
public:

    void lock_shared(void)
    {
        // If there is a unique operation running, wait for it to finish.
        if( this->_is_blocked ){
            // Use a shared lock to let all shared actions through as soon as the unique action finishes.
            std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> l(this->_unique_mutex);
        }

        // Allow for multiple shared actions, but no unique actions.
        this->_shared_mutex.lock_shared();
    }

    void unlock_shared(void)
    {
        this->_shared_mutex.unlock_shared();
    }

    void lock(void)
    {
        // Avoid other unique actions and avoid new shared actions from being queued.
        this->_unique_mutex.lock();

        // Redirect shared actions to the unique lock.
        this->_is_blocked = true;

        // Perform the unique lock.
        this->_shared_mutex.lock();
    }

    void unlock(void)
    {
        this->_shared_mutex.unlock();
        this->_is_blocked = false;
        this->_unique_mutex.unlock();
    }

    std::shared_mutex _shared_mutex;
    std::shared_mutex _unique_mutex;
    std::atomic<bool> _is_blocked = false;
};
```

Comment: This sounds more like a topic for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) than Stack Overflow, as you've essentially posted what you claim to be working code and are asking for general feedback.  If, through your testing of this code, you discover it is not behaving as expected, then that would be an appropriate question to ask here provided that you back it up with testing methodology, findings and an actual question.

Comment: Your test of _is_blocked in lock_shared() is racing with your assignment of it in lock().  That miss would prevent it from doing whatever `std::shared_lock<std::shared_mutex> l(this->_unique_mutex);`  means; and presumably downgrades your assertion to *rarely starves*.

Comment: @mevets Thank you for the response. Some read requests might indeed pass the write request, so the processing order isn't guaranteed, but if I'm correct as soon as these additional read requests have been processed, the write process can do its thing.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code right, then this is equivalent:

```
1    my_shared_lock(Lock *p) {
2        if (p->_is_blocked) {
3             exclusive_lock(&p->x);
4        }
5        shared_lock(&p->s);
6    }
7    
8    my_exclusive_lock(Lock *p) {
9        exclusive_lock(&p->x);
10       p->_is_blocked = 1;
11       shared_lock(&p->s);
12   }
```

If you have two threads executing, and this displays their progress:

```
T1:   1  2  4  5
T2: 8 9     10 11
```

The key being that the test on line 2 may execute in one thread in between the execution of lines 9 and 10 in another; so line 3 is skipped.
Then T1 thinks it has `my_shared_lock` and T2 thinks it has `my_exclusive_lock` simultaneously, which is worse than starvation.

Comment: I don't think it's the same as I use two shared mutexes which both use a shared lock in the first function and a regular lock in the second one. Besides that, I believe that if in your code there is a race towards line 5 and 11, only one thread will lock that mutex and therefore only one will be allowed to continue. Right?